# How to use complex number "i" in C++

Tags: c++, overloading, complex-numbers, complextype

I am coding a simple DFT algorithm now and I want to use the complex number i in complex exponential. I saw somebody use `#include<complex>` and `#include<cmath>`, and then they used the overloaded symbol `I` such as `exp(2*I)` . But it seems it doesn't work in my visual studio compiler. So, can anyone give a simple example of using complex exponential? Thanks!

Comment: You could create a complex variable and assign it the value `sqrt(-1)`

Comment: But, really, I am curious if there exists such a convenient overloading symbol. I mean those who created c++ should have thought about it, right? :P but your idea is definitely good

Comment: @Cancan: And this symbol would be a `complex<float>`, `complex<double>` or `complex<long double>`? ;) By the way, `complex<double>{0, 1}` works fine too.

Comment: @Floris , sorry to ask an additional question. Do you know which library I should add to use complex sqrt? it seems my compiler always tells me there several instances of overloading function sqrt.

Comment: @syam , yea, I am using complex<double>. And thanks, I didn't know we can use this notation as well to express complex. :D

Comment: @Cancan - see my answer. The way I defined `i` as a complex number, set the value to `-1`, then called `sqrt`, I ensured that the correct version of `sqrt` would be called. Just calling `sqrt(-1)` will not automatically get you the right version of `sqrt` I should have been clearer in my initial comment.

Comment: You can use `1i`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a short complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
typedef complex<double> dcomp;

int main() {
  dcomp i;
  dcomp a;
  double pi;
  pi = 2 * asin(1);
  i = -1;
  i = sqrt(i);
  a = exp(pi*i) + 1.+0i;
  cout << "i is " << i << "and Euler was right: exp(i pi) + 1 = " << a << endl;
}
```

Tested with g++

Answer (score 13):

I get this question recently as well and find a easy way for future reader:

Just use `<complex>` library like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
using namespace std ;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const   complex<double> i(0.0,1.0);    
    cout << i << endl ;

    return(0) ;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way is to use [`std::literals::complex_literals::operator""i`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i) after C++14:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main() {
    using namespace std::complex_literals;
    auto c = 1.0 + 3.0i;
    std::cout << "c = " << c << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
c = (1,3)
```

Comment: This is the correct way and should be the accepted answer. This is the exact correspondence to C's complex j-literal.

Answer (score 3):

You can find details [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/)

A simple approach would be

```
#include <complex>

using std::complex;
const double pi = 3.1415;
void foo()
{
    complex<double> val(polar(1, pi/2.0); Create a complex from its olar representation
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code in  C++ shows a macro for implementing the imaginary number j.  It is well known that in programming the terms i and j are commonly used as counter variables.  I instead use the capital letter J to represent the imaginary number to avoid any confusion.

/ * dcomplex.h

```
#ifndef DCOMPLEX_H_
#define DCOMPLEX_H_
#define J dcomplex(0.0,1.0)
typedef std::complex<double> dcomplex;
#endif /* DCOMPLEX_H_ */
```

Using this macro, the imaginary number J [together with the complex library] can be used in the main code.  An example of its use is shown below:

```
....
....
#include <complex>
#include "dcomplex.h"

....
....
 tmp = tmp + t[n]*exp( (2.0*PI*(double)n*(double)l/(double)tab_size)*J );
....
```

....

where tmp, t[n] are variables of a complex type, and J is the imaginary number. The variables n, l, and tab_size are of an integer type. The constant PI is the well known constant 3.14... The function exp() is overloaded to handled complex numbers.  [n.b. this code sample is part of a simple DFT]

Using this macro, the code is more readable..

Answer (score 0):

*pi*, being an irrational number, cannot be exactly represented by a **double**.  **cos** of an inexact approximation of pi is likely to yield a result which is close to but perhaps not exactly 1.  Likewise **sin** of an inexact approximation of an inexact approximation of *pi* is like to result in a number is has a very small magnitude that is perhaps not exactly 0.  Why not just define I to be **std::complex(0.0, 1.0)** and avoid the gratuitous inexactness.