# C++, Error when combining complex numbers with normal doubles inside a for() function

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I am sorry if this problem is obvious but I just can't figure out whats wrong with my code. Explanation below, here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  //Variables:
  complex<double> c;  //Coordinate
  complex<double> zn;
  complex<double> znp1;


  double iteration;  //Iteration counter
  double limit = 1.0e3;  //zn must exceed limit


  double resolution = 50.0;     //Points/pixels per axis

  double realrangeplus =5.0;    //Coordinate system
  double realrangeminus = -5.0;
  double realsubdiv = (realrangeplus - realrangeminus)/resolution;

  double imagrangeplus = 5.0;
  double imagrangeminus = -5.0;
  double imagsubdiv = (imagrangeplus - imagrangeminus)/resolution;



  //cycle through real axis with c
  for(real(c) = realrangeminus; real(c) <= realrangeplus; real(c) = real(c) + realsubdiv){

    //cycle through imaginary axis with c
    for(imag(c) = imagrangeminus; imag(c) <= imagrangeplus; imag(c) = imag(c) + imagsubdiv){
      //==========================================

      iteration = 0.0;  //reset
      zn = (0.0, 0.0);
      znp1 = (0.0, 0.0);

      //Start iterating:
      do{
        iteration = iteration + 1.0; //count iterations

        zn = znp1;
        znp1 = zn*zn + c;

      }while(abs(zn)<=limit);



      cout << real(c) << " " << imag(c) << "      " << real(zn) << " " << imag(zn) << "    " << iteration << endl;

      //==========================================
    }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

And here is the error when compiling it with `g++ mandelbrot_skript.cpp` in an Ubuntu terminal or in eclipse:

```
mandelbrot_skript.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
mandelbrot_skript.cpp:32:17: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   for(real(c) = realrangeminus; real(c) <= realrangeplus; real(c) = real(c) + realsubdiv){
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mandelbrot_skript.cpp:32:79: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
   for(real(c) = realrangeminus; real(c) <= realrangeplus; real(c) = real(c) + realsubdiv){
                                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~
mandelbrot_skript.cpp:35:19: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     for(imag(c) = imagrangeminus; imag(c) <= imagrangeplus; imag(c) = imag(c) + imagsubdiv){
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mandelbrot_skript.cpp:35:81: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     for(imag(c) = imagrangeminus; imag(c) <= imagrangeplus; imag(c) = imag(c) + imagsubdiv){

                                                                             ^~~~~~~~~~
```

I am trying to create an image of the mandelbrot set and the code might be entirely wrong but that's not the point.

I don't understand why there is an error message. There are no spelling mistakes as far as I can see, all the variables have the correct datatype (I think) and I have successfully tried adding and multiplying the real and imaginary part with normal double variables. This error only shows up when I do that inside of the `for()` function. Strangely the exact same code executes without a problem inside of an android app called "CPP N-IDE".

So basically, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please take the habit of extracting and providing a [mcve] next time. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`real(c)` is a reader function. `c.real(value)` is the write function. [source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/real)

Thus:

```
for (c.real(realrangeminus); real(c) <= realrangeplus; c.real(real(c) + realsubdiv)) {
```

etc.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you. Do you know why the app didn't have a problem?

Comment: @EVARATE because the app probably doesn't know what to do. code interpretation is quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

[cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)

> For any pointer to an element of an array of complex named p and
>   any valid array index i, reinterpret_cast(p)[2*i] is the real part
>   of the complex number p[i], and reinterpret_cast(p)[2*i + 1] is
>   the imaginary part of the complex number p[i]

So, as previously said, `real(c)` and `imag(c)` would be the reader methods for the reading of the variables, not the setting of them.

Further information about the use of complex numbers can be found [on StackOverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925904/how-to-use-complex-number-i-in-c)